# Ionic back button not working even though ionicHistory back view exists

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, back-button

My  ionic back button doesn't do anything when it is being clicked even though, when I print out the version history, it shows that there is a back view. Also for some reason `$ionicHistory.enabledBack()` is returning false, even though the back view exists and the back view and current view have the same id. Does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Here's a snapshot of the console.

[image]

Comment: Did you do something like `disableBack` in your state change?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.. unless it is a default setting, but the docs say "disableBack: The next view should forget its back view, and set it to null.", but in this case my backview isn't null, so i don't know what it isn't working

Comment: how about `$state.go(backview);`

Comment: okay I got it to work by nesting the view properly with ui-router, but now, even though it goes back to the right state, the DOM isn't reloading the HTML page to the proper previous page, it just stays the same, even though the viewHistory properly updates.

Comment: Okay solved it, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `ui-router` nested views to create states that will replace an `ion-nav-view` tag in the HTML.
2. Use `ion-view`, not `ion-nav-view`, inside the template `html` for each nested view.

Example:

`Parent (Nav) View HTML`:

```
<ion-nav-view name="navView"></ion-nav-view>
```

`Nested View Level 1 HTML`:

```
<ion-view view-title="Nested View Level 1">
    <ion-content></ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

`Nested View Level 2 HTML`:

```
<ion-view view-title="Nested View Level 2">
    <ion-content></ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

`ui-router`:

```
$stateProvider
.state('app.navView', {
  url: '/nav-view',
  views: {
    'menuContent': {
      templateUrl: 'app/navView.html',
      controller: 'NavViewCtrl as vm'
    }
  }
})
.state('app.nestedViewL1', {
      url: '/nested-view-L1',
      views: {
        'navView': {
          templateUrl: 'app/nestedViewL1.html',
          controller: 'NestedView1CtrL1 as vm'
        }
      }
    })
.state('app.nestedViewL2', {
      url: '/nested-view-L2',
          views: {
            'navView': {
              templateUrl: 'app/nestedViewL2.html',
              controller: 'NestedViewL2Ctrl as vm'
            }
          }
        })
```